# LEGO figures from the loading screen of Instructions App

Tags: minifigure-identification

Where could I find these two LEGO minifigures? I've found this screenshot in the LEGO Instructions app.

[image]

Comment: That's interesting, [this piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb2346) appears to be the same printing as the left torso except the shirt color is different. I couldn't find an exact match.

Comment: I have the torso's in the Spike Prime education set, but indeed in different colors but same print.

Comment: Added the entire screeny of the app launch image, then broke them down to their alpha-numerical goody two shoes.

Comment: I can't figure out what kind of hoodie the girl is even wearing.  What is it?  A ninja scarf with pull strings? Can anyone provide a real life link to this type of clothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point in time we probably won't get an exact match for each piece, but this is what we've got so far:

- **A01**. *[Part #87991 - Minifigure, Hair Tousled with Side Part.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87991#T=C&C=11)*

  [image: ![enter image description here]
- **A02**. *Minifigure Head: Unknown ???*
- **A03**. *[Part #982pb062 - Arm, Right with Blue Short Sleeve
  Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=982pb062&name=Arm,%20Right%20with%20Blue%20Short%20Sleeve%20Pattern&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Part%5D#T=C)*.

  [image: ![enter image description here]

  *[Part #981pb062 - Arm, Left with Blue Short Sleeve Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=981pb062&name=Arm,%20Left%20with%20Blue%20Short%20Sleeve%20Pattern&category=[Minifigure,%20Body%20Part]#T=C)*.

  [image: ![enter image description here]
- **A04**. *Minifigure Torso: Unknown ???*

  *Alexander O'Mara* and *Michael Verschaeve* have pointed out this unknown color variant of *[Part #973pb2346 - Torso Hoodie with Zipper
  over Lime and Green Striped Shirt Pattern.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb2346#T=C&C=153)*

  [image: ![enter image description here]
- **A05**. [*Part #53118pb01- Minifigure, Utensil Video Game Controller
  with Silver Controls, Blue and Red Buttons Pattern.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=53118pb01&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Video%20Game%20Controller%20with%20Silver%20Controls,%20Blue%20and%20Red%20Buttons%20Pattern&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=11)

  [image: ![enter image description here]
- **A06**. *[Part #41879 - Legs Short.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41879&idColor=86#T=C&C=86)*

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

- **B01**. [*Part #15427 - Minifigure, Hair Female Ponytail Off-center.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15427#T=C&C=120)

  [image: ![enter image description here]
- **B02**. *Minifigure Head: Unknown ???*
- **B03**. [*Part #981982 - Arm, (Matching Left and Right) Pair.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=981982&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

  [image: ![enter image description here]
- **B04**. *Minifigure Torso: Unknown ???*

  *Michael Verschaeve* has further pointed out this unknown color variant of *[Part #973pb2680 - Torso Female Hoodie with White Laces,
  Blue Scrollwork, Kangaroo Pocket Pattern.](https://brickset.com/parts/6176217/mini-upper-part-no-3688)*

  [image]
- **B05**. *Minifigure Utensil: Unknown 2x2 Tile w/Instructions App Pattern???*

  [image]
- **B06**. *[Part #41879 - Legs Short.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41879&idColor=86#T=C&C=1)*

  [image: ![enter image description here]
- "**?**" *Minifigure Utensil: Unknown Utensil in Girl's left hand???*

  [image]

Comment: Becacause there're unknown parts, can we decide that the picture is photoshopd?

Comment: Let's think about what we can say and can not say...  We can't say it's been Photoshoped just becasue they use parts currently not in Bricklink's inventory.  What if they aren't using the Photoshop program itself to forge these unknown smiles, but the 3D rendering software they used from their movies to make facial expressions?  What if they have parts like the torsos that simply haven't been released in a set yet, and that's why we can't find them.?  So, at this point in time,  we probably won't get an exact match, or get a definite answer, until we ask LEGO directly, or wait for more info.

Comment: I may suggest to improve this answer by providing colors for each known part. They are quite easy to identify and contribute to exact part identification.

Comment: Have at it, Alex. The links do point to the right corresponding colored pictures on BrickLink.   Didn't include on this end because with some parts I couldn't decipher exactly which color it was.  For ex. the girl's hair.  Is it Dark Brown or is it Reddish-Brown? How about the blue on the sleeves?  Is what's available on BL the same blue (Dark Azure) as the guy's sleeves?  On this end my initial scenario was to either name them all, or don't label any.  But, hey, I'll leave this to you, if you're game to do it right.  Also, I didn't include minifig fingers of either figure too.

Comment: Edited this answer to indicate that the 2nd torso is also known in different colors (B04) https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=154627 https://brickset.com/parts/6176217/mini-upper-part-no-3688

Comment: My edits seem undone ? Perhaps Rin Rio-Oki can edit himself?

Comment: Thanks Michael Verschaeve.  Was currently scrolling through 83 pages of Torsos 200 deep looking for a variant color.  Your eyes must be beet red.  I have my browser magnification to 300%, but was still feeling my brain sliding out one ear...

Comment: @RinRio-Oki. Regarding the edit -> probably my mistake. About the torso, didn't need to search, I have it. It's also in the spike prime set like the other torso.

Comment: In the second picture the girl's left leg (to the right on the picture) seems to be pointing a little forward/(her )left, which the short legs can't do, so they might be longer (I think there are three different parts they could be) - but as much indicates that this is a rendering rather than a photograph of real parts, that might also just be an artistic liberty.

Comment: @ Henrik, yeah, I'm leaning more toward a liberal artistic zeal of those pesky designers vs. them switching in long legs.  Take a moment.  Step back and look at the overall image.  What message is it saying to the viewer? Can we agree that the boys legs are short?  So, If his legs are short, and her legs are long, what story is the image telling us?  Is he hanging out with his long legged older sister or mom?  Nah, LEGO's targeted audience, their main demographic group, are youngsters.  Look at their outfits:  Gamer casual hoodies and game controllers. To much overall evidence for short legs.